# Task async and continuewith

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

I'm trying to get data from server and afterwards I need to do few things with that data and other functions.

Because I'm getting data from server I did it with async and continuewith functions.

This is my code:

```
private void login(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    SharedFunctions.showHide("Show", pBar, txt);
    result = false;
    if (validateScreen())
    {
        Task task = new Task(() => LoginUser().ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            afterLogin();
        }));
        task.Start();
    }
}

private void afterLogin()
{
    if (result)
    {
        SharedFunctions.saveDataOnDevice(userID, storeID, permission);

        StartActivity(typeof(SplashScreen));
        Finish();
    }
    else
    {
        SharedFunctions.showHide("Hide", pBar, txt);
        SharedFunctions.showPopUp(this, GetString(Resource.String.error_login), GetString(Resource.String.wrong_name_and_password));
    }
}

private async Task LoginUser()
{
    string userName = uName.Text;
    string password = pass.Text;
    password = SharedFunctions.encrypt(password);

    var client = new RestClient("........");
    string resourceStr = @"api/base/....";
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
    {
        Resource = resourceStr,
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
    };
    request.AddBody(new { UserName = userName, Password = password });
    var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<dynamic>(request);

    var dt = response.Data;

    if (dt != null)
    {
        userID = dt["ID"];
        storeID = dt["StoreID"];
        permission = dt["Permission"];

        result = true;
    }
    else
        result = false;
}
```

My main problem is that after I get the data, right after this code: `if (dt != null)`.

When I try to debug the code it reaches the row with `userID = dt["ID"];` and even before it is executed it jumps to the `afterLogin()` function.

What do I need to change in my code to make it run the entire functions before going to the next?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about enabling break when exception is thrown while debugging.

Comment: Why are you using `ContinueWith` instead of `await`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very different.

I found out that I cannot convert var that was in the dynamic object to int and that is why the program stopped.

I change this row: userID = dt["ID"]; to this: userID = Convert.ChangeType(dt["ID"], typeof(int));

And now it works.

Thank you all for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

As I describe on my blog, you should never use [the `Task` constructor](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) or [the `Start` method](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html). They are extremely outdated ways to execute code on a thread pool thread, which your app doesn't even need to do since `LoginUser` is asynchronous. If you *did* need to execute code on a thread pool thread, the correct API is `Task.Run`, but in this case you don't need it.

As a side note, you [should not use `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) in this situation, either (also explained on my blog). In fact, [`ContinueWith` is downright dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html); you should use `await` instead.

After applying these best practices:

```
private async void login(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  SharedFunctions.showHide("Show", pBar, txt);
  result = false;
  if (validateScreen())
  {
    await LoginUser();
    afterLogin();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When it jumps out that means that the Task breaks (exception) but it doesn't break the whole program as this is an async Task.

Make a breakpoint right threre and check what is inside `dt`.
Especially with strings like `"ID"` you often have errors like these. It might be as well `"Id"` or `"id"` which is not equal nill but also not matching your `"ID"`.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Task.ContinueWith starts only after completion of the original task.
I'm not sure if this'll help you but try this

```
private void login(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    SharedFunctions.showHide("Show", pBar, txt);
    result = false;
    if (validateScreen())
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { LoginUser(); }).ContinueWith((t) => { afterLogin(); });
    }
}
```

And make your login a normal void function.